# Execute SQL Server stored procedure from VBA and retrieve all messages and result sets

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ado

I want to be able to execute a SQL Server stored procedure from MS Access VBA, in such a way that I can read (1) all the resulting result sets, not just the first one; and (2) any messages produced by PRINT statements or similar.

I have a test stored procedure with one input parameter, which produces 3 distinct result sets and about 90 messages. It calls several sub-stored procedures, I can EXEC it perfectly well from SSMS, but it isn’t clear (to me) how best to do it from Access VBA. I have tried the following so far:

1. DAO. Using SQL pass-through queries, I can get a lot of what I want in DAO, though it is a little clunky. It returns the first of the 3 result sets as a recordset, and by using the LogMessages attribute I can get a table (“Admin – NN”) containing the emitted messages.
2. ADO. Using Connection and Command objects, I can obtain a single recordset representing the first result set from the stored procedure. However, I can’t seem to persuade it to produce anything but a forward-only recordset. Regarding messages, at one point, all of them (at least, the first 127 of the approx. 150 I expected) were going into the connection’s Errors collection (!), but when I cut the number down to about 90, none of them appeared anywhere at all that I could find.

What I really want, as I said at first, is the output from **all result sets**, **plus the messages**. Is this possible?

Here is a listing of the routine I am currently using for executing a stored procedure :

```vb
Function ExecuteStoredProcedureADO(SPName As String, Connect As String, ReturnsRecords As Boolean, _
   ParamArray Params() As Variant) As ADODB.Recordset
   ' v1.0 2018/06/26
   ' execute stored procedure SPName on a SQL Server database specified by the string in Connect

   Dim strErr As String
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim lngRecsAffected As Long

   Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
   Dim errCurr As ADODB.Error
   Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

   On Error GoTo Catch
   Set ExecuteStoredProcedureADO = Nothing

   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
   cnn.Errors.Clear
   cnn.mode = adModeRead
   cnn.CommandTimeout = 300
   cnn.Open Connect

   Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
   With cmd
      .ActiveConnection = cnn
      .CommandText = SPName
      .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

      For i = 0 To UBound(Params) Step 4
         .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(Params(i), Params(i + 1), adParamInput, Params(i + 2), Params(i + 3))
      Next i
      Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
      rst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
      If ReturnsRecords Then
         '''Set rst = .Execute(lngRecsAffected)
         rst.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
      Else
         Set rst = .Execute(, , adExecuteNoRecords)
      End If
   End With
   If ReturnsRecords Then Set ExecuteStoredProcedureADO = rst

Final:
   On Error Resume Next
   If Len(strErr) > 0 Then Call AppendMsg(strErr)
   Set rst = Nothing
   Set cmd = Nothing
   Exit Function

Catch:
   If cnn.Errors.Count > 0 Then
      With cnn
         For Each errCurr In cnn.Errors
            strErr = strErr & "Error " & errCurr.Number & ": " & errCurr.Description _
               & " (" & errCurr.Source & ")" & vbCrLf
         Next errCurr
         strErr = Left(strErr, Len(strErr) - 2) ' truncate final CRLF
      End With
   Else
      strErr = "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & " (" & Err.Source & ")"
   End If
   MsgBox strErr, vbOKOnly, gtitle
   Resume Final

End Function
```

Addendum: Regarding the multiple result sets, I am hoping that [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677569%28VS.85%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677569%28VS.85%29.aspx/) 
will be of some help.

Comment: `NextRecordSet` should work fine. You just loop through them. I've never done it with SQL Server procedure returns, but I've done it with 15 results sets returned from a Teradata procedure for a productionalized report and it works great. Not sure on the "messages" though.

Comment: To retrieve messages, you need to use ADO inside a class, declare the connection in the class scope with `WithEvents`, and use the Connection_InfoMessage event. I'd write up a complete answer but I'm currently on my phone

Answer (score 3):

To shamelessly piggy-back off of @Erik, you want to create a new class that will handle your processing. Something like `cProcedureHandler`. Within this class, you need to declare an `ADODB.Connection` object using the `WithEvents` keyword:

```
Dim WithEvents cn As ADODB.Connection
```

Then, you need to write a `InfoMessage` event handler that will take care of the multiple print statements. Information about the `InfoMessage` event can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/infomessage-event-ado?view=sql-server-2017), and using the connection's `Errors` collection can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/provider-errors?view=sql-server-2017). So you'll end up with something like this:

```
  Private Sub cn_InfoMessage(ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
     Dim err As ADODB.Error

     Debug.Print cn.Errors.Count & " errors"

     For Each err In cn.Errors
        ' handle each error/message the way you need to.
        Debug.Print err.Description
     Next err
  End Sub
```

Since you've taken care of the code to handle multiple messages, now you just need to handle the multiple recordsets, which is explained pretty well in the link you provided. One thing I noticed was that the example link used `rs is nothing` as the check for when there were no more recordsets, which didn't work for me. I had to use the rs `State` property. So I ended up with this:

```
  Public Sub testProcedure()
     Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
     Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
     Dim recordSetIndex As Integer

     Set cn = modData.getConnection

     Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
     cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
     cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
     cmd.CommandText = "dbo.sp_foo"

     Set rs = cmd.Execute

     recordSetIndex = 1

     Do Until rs.State = ObjectStateEnum.adStateClosed
        Debug.Print "contents of rs #" & recordIndex
        Do Until rs.EOF
           Debug.Print rs.Fields(0) & rs.Fields(1)
           rs.MoveNext
        Loop

        Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
        recordSetIndex = recordIndex + 1
     Loop

     cn.Close
     Set rs = Nothing
     Set cn = Nothing
     Set cmd = Nothing

  End Sub
```

Then, when you're ready to run your SP from VBA, just do something like this:

```
set obj = new cProcedureHandler
obj.testFooProcedure
```

Another thing (you probably have already done this): Make sure your actual stored procedure in SQL Server sets nocount on.

Comment: Excellent answer. If I don't write one up, you're always free to use the info I provided in the comments.

Comment: @Zack Does the event get raised just once, or every time a message is emitted? I was expecting the latter as the event handler just has a single Error object rather than an Errors collection, but the event was only raised once when I tried it, and that was with the message:  265929: No more results. (Provider) Status:1 I was expecting 90-odd messages.

Comment: You don't want to use the `pError` object passed in the event (which, as you note, is only 1 error), bur rather use the connection's `Errors` collection, which will contain all the errors/messages you need.