# ADODB.Connection InfoMessage Event never get's fired

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, oledb, ado

I post this as new question because the answers in post [Execute SQL Server stored procedure from VBA and retrieve all messages and result sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51327395/execute-sql-server-stored-procedure-from-vba-and-retrieve-all-messages-and-resul) didn't solve my problem.

I use MS Access as frontend to SQL Server and would like to get progress messages back from long running multi-statement SQL procedures, but the InfoMessage event never get's fired. I put `Print` and `RaiseError` statements with different severity levels in my stored procedure. Also tried to execute a command object based on the connection, and different OLDDB providers (SQLNCLI10, SQLNCLI11, MSOLEDBSQL, SQLOLEDB)

The ExecuteComplete event gets fired correctly when the sql procedure ends. The pError Parameter is set to "Executing 1st statement ...", and - surprisingly - the Connection.Errors collection contains three errors: "Executing 1st statement ...", "Now for a print statement" and "Executing 3rd statement ..."

Here is my SQL Code:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE TestCommunication 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    RAISERROR('Executing 1st statement ...', 1, 1) WITH NOWAIT
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

    RAISERROR('Executing 2nd statement ...', 10, 10) WITH NOWAIT
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

    PRINT 'Now for a Print-statement!'
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'

    RAISERROR('Executing 3rd statement ...', 16, 16) WITH NOWAIT
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

    RAISERROR('Completing ...', 16, 10) WITH NOWAIT
END
GO
```

And that's my VBA code:

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private WithEvents conn As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub conn_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "Execution ended"
End Sub

Private Sub conn_InfoMessage(ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print pError.Description
End Sub

Public Sub RunQuery(strQuery As String)

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = getADODBConnectionString        'Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=adgpcr.res2.loc.lan.at;Database=CostDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;APP=CostDB;
    conn.Open
    conn.Execute strQuery, , adExecuteNoRecords + adAsyncExecute

End Sub
```

```vb
Public Sub TestMessages()
    
    Set o = New ADODBQuery    'ADODBQuery is the name of the class above
    o.RunQuery "dbo.TestCommunication"

End Sub
```

As recommended by Erik A I added functionality to run the stored procedure through a command object:

```
Public Sub RunProcedure(strProcedureName As String)

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = getADODBConnectionString
    conn.Open
    
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = strProcedureName
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    
    cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords + adAsyncExecute

End Sub
```

Same result as executing the stored procedure from the connection object.

Interesting fact: when omitting the options adExecuteNoRecords + adAsyncExecute the ExecuteComplete event is fired immediately (expected) and afterwards the InfoMessage event is fired once (!) with pError and the Errors collection of the connection object set to the first RAISERROR message!?!

Any comments on what I'm missing?

Comment: Your code looks nothing like the duplicate linked though, you're not using an ADO command and are calling the query as text, instead of using `adCmdStoredProc` to evaluate a specific stored procedure. Have you tried to use similar code? Can you share the exact attempt?

Comment: The last time a very similar question to this was asked wasn't the advice to check the pConnection.Errors collection as per the [Provider Errors documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/provider-errors)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: when should I check the pConnection.Errors collection when the InfoMessage event never get's fired?

Comment: @ErikA: edited my question to include code you recommended.

Comment: @AndreasKormann This line: `cmd.ActiveConnection = conn` is problematic, it causes your command object to use a different connection, since you don't use `Set`, the connection is cast to a string, and then a new connection is created using that string. It should be `Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn`

Comment: @ErikA: no, this makes no difference. Tried this before. And the ExecuteComplete event is fired, so the connection seems to be correctly set.